# Apex charts disable scrolling / zooming

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, apexcharts

I have built a chart using the [ApexCharts](https://apexcharts.com/) library and I want to disable the possibility of dragging the chart. How should I update my configurations (see below)? I couldn't find any detail in the documentation. This is my chart:

```
//My component
<Chart
  options={performanceLineChart.options}
  series={performanceLineChart.series}
/>

//My configurations
export const performanceLineChart = {
  options: {
    chart: {
      id: 'my-chart',
      type: 'line' as 'line',
      toolbar: {
        show: false //Disable toolbar
      }
    },
    stroke: {
      width: 5,
      curve: 'smooth' as 'smooth'
    },
    markers: {
      size: 4,
      hover: {
        size: undefined,
        sizeOffset: 2
      }
    },
    xasis: {
      type: 'numeric',
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Line 1',
    data: [
      [3066, 323],
      [6317, 312],
      [12498, 313],
      [24091, 326]
    ]
  },{
    name: 'Line 2',
    data: [
      [3516, 281],
      [7378, 268],
      [11502, 344],
      [21219, 371]
    ]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you're talking about selection zoom, you can turn it off like this

```
chart: {
  id: 'my-chart',
  type: 'line' as 'line',
  toolbar: {
    show: false
  },
  zoom: {
    enabled: false,
  }
},
```

Comment: This hides  (+ -) icons as well. I want  (+ -) icons and just want to disable zoom with mouse selection . do you have any workaround for that?

Comment: Set  `zoom: false` in `chart` -> `toolbar` -> `tools` https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/toolbar/#zoom